# How to increase numerical accuracy of Pytorch model?

Tags: python, pytorch

With the following line:

```
print(self.netG(self.real_A)-self.netG(self.real_A))
```

I think I can get a all zero tensor, but no.

```
tensor([[ [[-0.0032,  0.0089, -0.0085,  ..., -0.0027,  0.0004, -0.0022],
          [-0.0019, -0.0022,  0.0775,  ...,  0.0236, -0.0277, -0.0125],
          [ 0.0049,  0.0159,  0.0203,  ..., -0.0212,  0.0010, -0.0069],
          ...,
          [ 0.0042,  0.0081, -0.0127,  ..., -0.0097,  0.0136, -0.0002],
          [-0.0010,  0.0020, -0.0066,  ...,  0.0260,  0.0433,  0.0088],
          [-0.0023,  0.0095,  0.0125,  ...,  0.0005,  0.0090,  0.0029]]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
```

Comment: Please review the following documentation and update your question.  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is self.netG !! you need to explain your question very well and provide the desired output etc..

Answer (score 0):

When working with floating point values, [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) of some real-valued operations is not preserved. This means for instance, that there is no guarantee that `(a + b) + c == a + (b + c)`.

In most code you deal with daily the order of operations is fixed, so you only ever get to observe `(a + b) + c` or `a + (b + c)` (depending on the programmer wrote it), but in PyTorch, on CUDA backend, there are series of such operations which are not deterministically ordered (due to parallelism). This means that on one run of your `self.netG(self.real_A)` you can observe `(a + b) + c` and on another `a + (b + c)`. Without seeing your code one can't tell, but it is a likely the source of your surprise. A bit more is given in [PyTorch docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html#pytorch).

EDIT: obviously, you can also switch your computations to 64-bit floating point numbers, which will improve the numerical accuracy (as it is commonly defined) of your calculations but is unlikely to help with nondeterminism (which is what you're actually complaining about).

Answer (score 0):

model.eval()
 This has any effect only on certain modules. See documentations of
        particular modules for details of their behaviors in training/evaluation
        mode, if they are affected, e.g. :class:`Dropout`, :class:`BatchNorm`,
        etc.